# Pass options to command in function in Bash

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I want to pass command options to a command in function.

For example,

I have a following script, which works with youtube-dl, stream youtube video URL with vlc media player.

```
youtube-stream(){
    youtube-dl -i -o - "$(cuturlquerystr "$1" | perl -pe "chomp")" | vlc.exe -
}
```

vlc has a number of command line options. I want to use those options from `youtube-stream` command.

Something like,

```
youtube-stream --pitch-shift="1.5" --rate="1.1" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RVea-2Up8xM"
```

The above command means,

```
youtube-dl -i -o - "$(cuturlquerystr "$1" | perl -pe "chomp")" | vlc.exe - --pitch-shift="1.5" --rate="1.1"
```

I'd like to implement that by something like following.

```
youtube-stream(){
    youtube-dl -i -o - "$(cuturlquerystr "$1" | perl -pe "chomp")" | vlc.exe - ${options}
}
```

I know getopt parsing method but I want to implement that by a small amount of code as possible as simple. Any idea?

Comment: Note that the `$()` command substitution mechanism strips trailing newlines already, you don't need to call perl to do it. [Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution). Does `cuturlquerystring` do something different?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. `cuturlquerystring` makes cut query string which is after `&` of a URL.

Comment: I think you could replace that command substitution with `"${1%%&*}"` that strips off everything after the *first* `&` from the first parameter.

Comment: It's a better idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the first argument in a variable, shift it out of the argument list, then you can pass all the remaining arguments to `vlc.exe` with `"$@"`.

```
youtube-stream(){
    local url=$1
    shift
    youtube-dl -i -o - "$(cuturlquerystr "$url" | perl -pe "chomp")" | vlc.exe - "$@"
}
```